# How to write list of dictionaries in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write list of dictionaries in JSON file, but I am experiencing difficulties which causes to create list for every dict and also missing commas after every dict.

What I tried so far:

```
data_list = [data]

with open('data.json', 'a') as out_file:
    json.dump([data.__dict__ for data in data_list], out_file)
```

Result I got:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "task_id": "task_1",
    "link": "https://google.com",
    "title": "Google",
    "message": "Redirect",
    "hits": 0
  }
][
  {
    "id": "2",
    "task_id": "task_2",
    "link": "https://fb.com",
    "title": "Facebook",
    "message": "Redirect",
    "hits": 0
  }
]
```

This is the expected behavior in the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "task_id": "task_1",
    "link": "https://google.com",
    "title": "Google",
    "message": "Redirect",
    "hits": 0
  },

  {
    "id": "2",
    "task_id": "task_2",
    "link": "https://fb.com",
    "title": "Facebook",
    "message": "Redirect",
    "hits": 1
  }
]
```

Also tried with `json.dumps()` which didn't return anything.

Comment: can you post the sample input

Comment: please add your input `dictionary`

Comment: how does data_list  look like?

Comment: It looks like you are appending to a file so each time you write to that file you will get a new array. You can't expect the file to be intelligent and merge the arrays, you have to do that yourself. If you need to append your content to the previously existing one yoiu will have to load the previously existing array, append the new dictionary, and rewrite the file with the whole array.

Comment: `data` dict looks like the results i got, but without the list brackets. So I am adding the dict to a list and then trying to dump it in json.

Comment: @Adirio using `w` instead of `a`  rewrites the previous result and instead of 2 results I get only 1. Not sure how that works

Comment: You have to add all the dictionaries to the same list and then dump that list. You cant add each one to a separate list, dump each one and expect the file to magically merge the lists, it will append them as you have seen in your output file.